# How to set expire-groups-upon-completion with @Aggregator annotation?

Tags: spring-integration

The reference manul talked about how to set this in XML, and I saw the [Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3732) for advanced configuration for `@Aggregator` completed but not seeing those advanced properties. So if using annotation, how to set expire group?

Answer (score 1):

Well, according that JIRA ticket there is indeed a sample in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-annotations):

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "aggregatorChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler aggregator(MessageGroupStore jdbcMessageGroupStore) {
     AggregatingMessageHandler aggregator =
                       new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(),
                                                 jdbcMessageGroupStore);
     aggregator.setOutputChannel(resultsChannel());
     aggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(500L));
     aggregator.setTaskScheduler(this.taskScheduler);
     return aggregator;
}
```

And there is an explicit note on the matter:

> Annotation configuration (`@Aggregator` and others) for the `Aggregator` component covers only simple use cases, where most default options are sufficient. If you need more control over those options using Annotation configuration, consider using a `@Bean` definition for the `AggregatingMessageHandler` and mark its `@Bean` method with `@ServiceActivator`

Even would be better to use this:

> Starting with the version 4.2 the `AggregatorFactoryBean` is available, to simplify Java configuration for the `AggregatingMessageHandler`.

Seems for me everything is covered in the Docs. Is anything missed?

I mean the `AggregatorFactoryBean` has an option you need:

```
public void setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(Boolean expireGroupsUponCompletion) {
```

Is that not enough?